# In calculating Clebsch-Gordan coefficients, is there a restriction on when the recursion relations can be used?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, angular-momentum, quantum-spin

So let's consider the case of $j_1=3/2,j_2=1/2$. We know from a table that the Clebsch Gordan Coefficient should be one. However, we also know that the recursion relation, referencing Zettili Quantum Mechanics, is given by
$$\sqrt{(j\mp m)(j\pm m+1)}\langle j_1 j_2;m_1 m_2|j,m\pm 1\rangle=\sqrt{(j_1\pm m_1)(j_1\mp m_1+1)}\langle j_1 j_2;m_1\mp 1,m_2|jm\rangle+\sqrt{(j_2\pm m_2)(j_2\mp m_2+1)}\langle j_1 j_2;m_1,m_2\mp 1|jm\rangle$$
However, if we plug in, for $m=2$ with $m_1=3/2,m_2=1/2$, and the aforementioned $j_1,j_2$ values, we get
$$\sqrt{(3/2+3/2)(3/2-3/2+1)}\langle3/2,1/2;1/2,1/2\rangle+\sqrt{(1/2+1/2)(1/2-1/2+1)}\langle{3/2,1/2; 3/2,-1/2\rangle} $$
Which is equal to
$$\sqrt{3}\langle3/2,1/2;1/2,1/2\rangle+\langle{3/2,1/2; 3/2,-1/2\rangle} $$
Invoking the normalization condition,
$$\left(\sqrt{(3/2+3/2)(3/2-3/2+1)}\langle3/2,1/2;1/2,1/2\rangle\right)^2+\left(\sqrt{(1/2+1/2)(1/2-1/2+1)}\langle{3/2,1/2; 3/2,-1/2\rangle}\right)^2=1 $$
We get that the CGC is not 1, but $\frac{1}{4}$.

There is obviously some mistake I am making here, but I am following the recursion relation formula. So is there some kind of restriction on using it as opposed to simply using the annihilation operator $\hat{J}_{-}$?

Comment: Where did you find that normalization condition?

Comment: It is in Zettili Quantum Mechanics, equation 7.125

Comment: Aren't your expectation values missing the $|jm\rangle$ or $|j, m\pm 1\rangle$ parts? Also how are you computing $j$ from $j_1$ and $j_2$?

Comment: As $|jm\rangle$ are constant and I am focused on the coefficient rather than the ket, I have excluded them. And $j=2$, as $j_1=s_1=3/2$ and $j_2=s_2=1/2$, this means $j=j_1+j_2=2$(this is a case for orbital AM =0)

Comment: The kets you skipped would have alerted you to the entire brackets vanishing, by virtue of mismatched *m* s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are misusing the  recursion.  All brackets where the (summed) *m*s don't match up between bras and kets vanish.

It looks like you are choosing the upper sign, so, indeed, you are verifying that 0=0+0.  You did not witness a failure of the identity.

To find a nontrivial example, instead, consider $m_1=3/2; ~~m_2=1/2; ~~m=1;~~j=2$, and take the upper signs again, for the sake of argument:
$$
2\langle  3/2~1/2; 3/2~1/2| 2~2\rangle = \sqrt{3} \langle 3/2~1/2   ; 1/2~1/2   | 2~1\rangle  +\langle  3/2~1/2  ; 3/2~-\!1/2   | 2~1\rangle  \\
2= 3/2 +1/2.
$$
Can you replicate the CG table, now?

Comment: Yes, I realized a bit later. Thanks for the answer anyways